# Seat Layout Using Python with jinja for loop?

Tags: python, html

As i'm doing seat layout for bus  according to my condition the layout is working properly but my problem is i have 40 available seats inside my for loop  i just want to print my 40 available seats inside my layout if the value is there means the seat will be printed else empty value will print.I tried up-to my best level please can any one help me.

here is my HTML:

Seat Layouts open -->

```
<div class="container w3-card-2" style="background-color:#fff;margin-left: -14px;">
  {% if z==0 %}
  <div style="border:1px solid #9E9E9E;border-left:3px solid #03a9f4;border-radius:3px;padding: 10px 0px 0px 10px;;width: 100%;background:#eee;margin-bottom:15px;  margin-top:10px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-11">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table_scroll_manual" style="margin:0px;">
            {% for dyro_id in i %} {% for dyco in j %} {% for one,two in jump %}
            <tr style="height:51px">


              <td>

                <div>
                  <span><img src="{{url_for('static',filename=img)}}" style="width:35px;transform:rotate(-90deg);margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;"></span>
                </div>

              </td>


            </tr>
            {% endfor %} {% endfor %} {% endfor %}
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  {% endif %}
</div>
```

from this code  i got output like this

[image]

but my expected output is like:

[image]

with this code i'm using python for back-end
in this HTML

```
      {% for dyro_id in i %}
      {% for dyco in j %}
```

this for loop is for seat layout `'i'` is list of row values and `'j'` is list of column values according to this condition my layout will works but my problem is in this looping statement `{% for one,two in jump %}` 
here `jump` contain two list from this i fetch values parallely from this for loop i got my exact values but i need to print images based on this for loop inside my layout Please can any one help me.